# Topic closed as being primarily opinion-based, but I disagree. Can I do something?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35997561/) which was closed due to being primarily opinion-based.

In fact, the non chosen answers were undoubtedly opinion-based. However, I think my answer proposed a concrete solution which was not opinion-based and I honestly believe it can help people in a similar situation. Besides, who knows, somebody might think of a better yet solution which is also not opinion-based.

That said, should this question really remain closed? If not, what could I do to request reopening? It's worth mentioning that it's not applicable to follow the banner's suggestion of editing the question since I just don't think it's opinion-based as it is.

Comment: _"If not, what could I do to request reopening?"_ Just what you were told at the banner.

Comment: The only instruction there is to edit the question, which I don't think is necessary since I just don't think it's opinion-based as it is. Maybe it's worth adding this much in my question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> My question: What character could I use that looks to the human eye like a separator AND is virtually guaranteed to not be used in song names and artist names?

There are any number of characters that could be used and none of them would really be any better than the others, so you'd be likely to get lots of different answers if that question was on-topic. It's no different than asking "What’s your favorite ______?", which is listed as off-topic in [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

That question might be salvageable if you change it to ask how to choose a delimiter in general, given certain restrictions, but even that seems only  borderline programming-related to me. It would be up to a vote whether it would stay open or not.

Comment: I understand, and I agree.

Answer (score 6):

Primarily opinion-based might not be the correct close reason, but do you really think that this question covers:

> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

If not, it's not [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I think it fits perfectly in the software algorithm category, but maybe that's subjective or I'm just plain wrong.

Comment: @lucasnadalutti It's not asking about a software algorithm at all.  It's asking what separator he should use in some data.  That's not an algorithm.

Answer (score 6):

The question is actually an XY problem.

The OP thinks that the problem is "how to choose a delimiter?", but the problem is actually "how can I always find the `uniqueID` in this string?".

If you look at that problem you see that the answer (or perhaps one answer) is to scan the string backwards until you find your known delimiter. Everything before the string is the one thing, everything after is the id.

It's not always easy to spot this sort of question, but when you do and if you can discover a solution to the actual problem then you can engage in a discussion with the OP to get the question into a better shape when it will become answerable.